# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

I am trying to implement one to many relationship in hibernate without the use of join table and facing a strange error. Can anyone help please?

**User.Java**

```
import java.util.Set;

public class User {

    private int id;
    private Set<Address> addresses;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<Address> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }

    public void setAddresses(Set<Address> addresses2) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }
}
```

**Address.java**

```
public class Address {

    private int id;
    private User user;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

**User.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="User"
     table="USER">
        <id name="id" column="user_id">
            <generator class="native">
                <param name="sequence">HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE
                </param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <set name="addresses" inverse="true">
        <key column="address_id"/>
        <one-to-many class="Address"/>
    </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Address.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Address"
     table="Address">
        <id name="id" column="address_id">
            <generator class="native">
                <param name="sequence">HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE
                </param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="user" 
        column="user_id"
        not-null="true"/>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Tester class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
public class HibernateTest {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    User user = new User();
    Address address1 = new Address();
    Address address2 = new Address();
    Address address3 = new Address();
    Address address4 = new Address();
    Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>();
    addresses.add(address1);addresses.add(address2);addresses.add(address3);        addresses.add(address4);
    user.setAddresses(addresses);
    SessionFactory factory = (new Configuration()).configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(user);
    session.save(address1);
    session.save(address2);
    session.save(address3);
    session.save(address4);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}

}
```

**Error staccktrace**

```
Apr 3, 2014 6:50:59 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
Hibernate: select HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE.nextval from dual
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : Address.user
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:106)
at     org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.nullifyTransientReferencesIfNotAlready(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:132)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.makeEntityManaged(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:141)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:199)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:177)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:164)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:332)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:137)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702)
at HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:38)
```

From the forums, i read the issue would resolved by the use of inverse="true" in User.xml but that is resolving the problem.

Can anyone help?

Comment: please indent your code to be more easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

in your user.hbm.xml

alter one to many as below

```
  <set name="addresses" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="address_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="Address" />
        </set>
```

and run it.

not null should be true in both mapping file.

let me know after executing it.

Answer (score 0):

In your mapping, you specified that the user property in the Address entity is not null.

```
 <many-to-one name="user" 
        column="user_id"
        not-null="true"/>
```

But in your code you are trying to save addresses with a null user property.You have to call
`address1.setUser(user)` before saving the address1 if you want to associate it with the user.

EDIT :
You made a mistake on the addresses setter the line

```
this.addresses = addresses;
```

Should be

```
this.addresses = addresses2;
```

Btw, you can add this method to the user entity

```
private void associateAddressesWithUser(){
    for(Address address : addresses) address.setUser(this);
}
```

and made these changes on the addresses setter (on the User entity)

```
   public void setAddresses(Set<Address> addresses2) {
       this.addresses = addresses2;
       associateAddressesWithUser(); 
   }
```